# Django Custom File Storage - write contents to file

Tags: django-admin

I'm trying to write a custom django backend that writes the contents of an uploaded file to an output file while also saving the file as it normally would.  I assumed I could do this by overriding the _open function of Django, but no luck.  Anyone know how to accomplish this? Here's what I've been messing around with

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class TestStore(FileSystemStorage):

```
    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):

            data = open(name, 'rb')
            dataRead = data.read()

            filename = '/home/somewhere/testdir/output.txt'

            FILE = open(filename, 'w')
            FILE.write(dataRead)
            FILE.close()
            data.close()

            return name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already created the file you can just output it with [content-disposition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment):

```
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='text/txt')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename'
```

Comment: I guess the file is already created, as it's uploaded by the user. But what I'd really like to set up is a custom storage system that goes like this:
[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/EBMvh3v2)